# Verbal problem with I think is exponential function! help.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with this exercise.

In a city of 5,000 inhabitants, the daily rate of infection with a flu virus varies directly with the product of infected people and the number of uninfected people. When 1,000 people have been infected, the flu spreads at a rate of 40 new cases per day. For what number of people infected, is the daily infection rate the highest? (using precalculus)

I used this exercise as a guide.

http://matema.ujaen.es/jnavas/web_modelos/problemas/ptema4.pdf

It is in Spanish. It is different but the context is quite similar. Here is a translation of it:

https://tinyurl.com/y7akm37r

So the function is

$$y(t)=\frac{5000}{1+Ae^{-rt}}$$
$$y(0)=\frac{5000}{1+Ae^{-r(0)}}$$
$$1=\frac{5000}{1+Ae^{0}}$$
$$1=\frac{5000}{1+A(1)}$$
$$1=\frac{5000}{1+A}$$
$$(1+A)\cdot1=\frac{5000}{1+A}\cdot (1+A)$$
$$(1+A)\cdot1=5000$$
$$1+A=5000$$
$$A=5000-1$$
$$A=4999$$

My question is $y(0)=1$ because in day 0 there is just 1 infected, the carrier? My other question is there any formula to determine that the function is $$y(t)=\frac{5000}{1+Ae^{-rt}}$$

Therefore,

$$y(t)=\frac{5000}{1+4999e^{-rt}}$$

Then, the problem says when 1,000 people have been infected, the flu spreads at a rate of 40 new cases per day. So is this right?

$$1000=\frac{5000}{1+4999e^{-40t}}$$

$$(1+4999e^{-40t})\cdot1000=\frac{5000}{1+4999e^{-40t}}\cdot(1+4999e^{-40t})$$
$$(1+4999e^{-40t})\cdot1000=5000$$
$$1000+4999000e^{-40t}=5000$$
$$4999000e^{-40t}=5000-1000$$
$$4999000e^{-40t}=4000$$
$$\frac{4999000e^{-40t}}{4999000}=\frac{4000}{4999000}$$
$$e^{-40t}=\frac{4}{4999}$$
$$\ln e^{-40t}=\ln\frac{4}{4999}$$
$$-40t\ln e=\ln\frac{4}{4999}$$
$$-40t(1)=\ln\frac{4}{4999}$$
$$-40t=\ln\frac{4}{4999}$$
$$\frac{-40t}{-40}=\ln\frac{4}{4999}\cdot\frac{1}{-40}$$
$$t=\ln\frac{4}{4999}\cdot\frac{1}{-40}$$
$$t\approx0.1783$$

So the function is:

$$y(t)=\frac{5000}{1+4999e^{-r\cdot0.1783}}$$
$$y(t)=\frac{5000}{1+4999e^{-0.1783r}}$$

Anyway, this is an exponential function, won't have a maximum. So then I came back to the same point in the circle where I started. :-( So I can't answer the question.

Please help.

Comment: See [the logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)

Comment: I don't follow this at all.  If the rate of infection varies directly with the product of the number of persons infected and those not infected, shouldn't the equation be $y(x)=Kx(5000-x)$ for some constant $K$, where $x$ is the number of people infected and $y$ is the daily infection rate?  You seem to be taking $y$ to be a function of time, although the problem statement says nothing about how the rate varies with time.

Comment: First, you can solve the diferential equation. After doing that you could take the derivative, find the time where it reaches the maximum, then evaluate $y(t)$ and find the solution. That's way much more work that they expect from you (solving a ODE and taking derivatives is not pre-calc). Second, $r$ is not the rate of infected, it's a constant defined in your PDF. Note that you ended with a function $y(t)$ with no variable $t$, that should say to you that there's something wrong. My answer is what they expect you to do (pre-calc) and the easy way to solve the question.

Answer (score 2):

For the question you want to answer there is no need in solving the diferential equation. The diferential equation you solved is
$$y'= \alpha y(K-y)$$
where $\alpha$ is a constant and $K$ is the total population.

When there are $y = 1000$ infected people, the rate of infection for a total population of $K = 5000$ is $y'=40$.

You plug the values into the diferential equation and you get $\alpha = 1*10^{-5}$
You have now the function
$$y'(y) = 1*10^{-5}y(5000-y)$$
which is a 2nd degree polinomial. Can you take it from there?

PD: computing $\alpha$ isn't necesary to know at what $y$ the maximum will be, but to know what will be the value maximum infection rate.

Edit: I forgot to answer 2 questions you asked in the middle.

1. $y(0)=1$ is the initial condition. That means that they decided to be 1 infected on day $0$.
2. There are no "formulas" to solve an ODE. In general it's not even posible to solve them analitically. There are many methods, but this particular ODE can be solved "separating variables". Again, you don't need to.

Comment: but how is done without using calculus? It is supposed to be done using pre-calculus. : - /

Comment: I haven't used calculus. I only have replaced values and now you have to solve a 2nd degree polinomial.